# Word 2013, VBA to create copy of Normal.dotm

Tags: vba, ms-word

My workplace is rolling out some large updates for Microsoft office. I'm trying to set up a VBA macro to run on everyone's computer to create a new folder with copies of Normal.dotm so that if (God forbid) something goes wrong we can restore the Normal.dotm. This is important because EVERYONE has a different ribbon layout and different macros and settings that we don't want lost.

My problem is I have a macro that is functionally fine, however when i try it on the Normal.dotm it gives the Permission Denied error because the FileCopy funtion cant work on Normal.dotm.

Code:

```
Private Sub CopyFiles_Click()
sUserName = Environ$("username")

Dim BackupDir As String
BackupDir = "C:\Users\" + sUserName + "\Desktop\Backup for Normal - DO NOT DELETE"

If FileFolderExists(BackupDir) Then
Else
    MkDir BackupDir
End If

If FileFolderExists("C:\Users\" + sUserName + "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm") Then
    FileCopy "C:\Users\" + sUserName + "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm", (BackupDir + "\Normal.dotm")
End If

End Sub
```

*I have a function for "FileFolderExists" i just didn't include it to save space (it works fine)*

My question is, is there any way to work around this (Been searching for a while and have come up empty handed), or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your problem is that Normal.dotm is "locked" when Word is running. If you run this code from, say, Excel with Word not running it might work... "Better way to do this" depends on how your company is set up. Is there a central IT administration that manages installation, user profiles, etc.? If yes, then "Group Policy" would be the way to go as that should be able to back up (and restore) files in the users' "Roaming" folders.

Answer (score 0):

Try this VBScript (Not VBA)

```
Dim sUserName
sUserName = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName

Dim BackupDir
BackupDir = "C:\Users\" + sUserName + "\Desktop\Backup for Normal - DO NOT DELETE"

dim filesys

set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
on error resume next
filesys.CreateFolder BackupDir
on error goto 0
filesys.CopyFile "C:\Users\" & sUserName & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm", (BackupDir & "\Normal.dotm")
```